# How to add "Share" button in html email?

Tags: css, html

I'm wondering if we can add a share button in emails only with HTML and CSS. If user clicks on button, it would open the popup with different sharing options like whatsapp, email etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to make popup in html emails. 
JS doesn't work in html emails due to security reasons and hacks like modal based on hidden checkbox should not work either.
If showing popup is critical you can dig into [AMP Emails](https://amp.dev/about/email.html), maybe there is something about modals.

But a bulletproof method is using just plain links for each social. For example sharing via Facebook should look somethink like 
`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=#url" target="_blank">Share</a>`
You can decorate links with social logo so it would look just like common share button